# Is there a task manager like application for visual studio?

Tags: visual-studio

Sometimes I experience Visual Studio 2010 being very sluggish. I have some plugins, like ReSharper for example, that I think could be the culprit. 
It would be nice if I could see the processes under visual studio to see what is using up all the CPU. Basically what I am looking for is a Task Manager just like the one in Google Chrome but for Visual Studio. I searched the internet and came up with nothing.

Answer (score 6):

Unlike Chrome, Visual Studio does not use multiple processes.  (Except when debugging applications)

Answer (score 2):

Using [Process Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) you can double click on your devenv.exe process, then under the Threads tab you can inspect, suspend or terminate (I wouldn't recommend the latter) threads belonging to addons, for example, VAssistX threads generally have a start address somewhere in the va_x.dll region.